# NavigationMixin : pages persist when going back

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datatable, navigation, lightningnavigation

So I have this setup where I have a searchfield that, upon button click, navigates to a results screen where there is a lightning datatable. 
Now, the problem is that if I go back from the results to the search and search for a new key, it will still show me the old results on the results screen.

Am only using lightning, no aura or VF pages.

My question: Is there a way to 'destroy' or 'clear' a page when I navigate back using the inherent back-button?
EDIT:
The real problem here is that the results page is not refreshed, since I can just refresh my browser page and then it will actually show the newer results. Just not after navigation is called, automatically. Results are not cached.

Thanks in advance.

I navigate like so:

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
         type: 'standard__component',
         attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__ResultsTab'
             },
         state: {
                c__data: JSON.stringify(this.foundData)
             }
         });
```

in the result screen controller I do:

```
@api set data(value) {
        this.items = [];
        this.items = JSON.parse(value);
    }
```

As far as I can see set data() isn't called anymore after I enter this screen for the first time.

So, what I want to do:
Search a > results a > back to Search > Search b > results b

what I get:
Search a > results a > back to Search > Search b > results a

Comment: `ResultsTab` - is this aura component?

Comment: As I said, I'm only using lightning, no aura or VF pages.

Comment: it is actually not possible to navigate to LWC component directly according to documentation. Can you please show full code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really do that. I can make a dummy version for you, sure.
However, ... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation ?

Comment: I worked on both aura and LWC. I will be able to help you if you show atleast a working demo here in question